# Finding the range and domain of an inverse trigonometric function.

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

I am trying to find the range and domain of the function :

### $\frac{(\sin^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}x-\cos^{-1}x-\cot^{-1}x)}{(\sin^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}x+\cot^{-1}x)}$

**My attempt:**

As $\sin^{-1}x$ has the smallest domain among the functions involved, the domain of the entire function should be $[-1,1]$. Now, I know that individual range of the functions and I am also aware of general properties of inverse trigonometric functions, but I am unable to find the range of this one.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that denominator appears to be constant, and all function in numerator are strictly increasing

Comment: This will look at lot better if you use "\sin x" instead of "sin x", etc. in the formatting.

Comment: Oh,thanks for pointing that out. I guess that makes it pretty obvious then.

Comment: The domain is given be $$-1\le x\le 1$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correctly determined the domain to be restricted to $[-1,1]$.

For the range, we note that denominator of the given function (call $f$) is a constant, that is $\pi$ and numerator is strictly increasing. So the range is $[f(-1),f(1)]$.